# No keyword with name 'Press Key Native' found

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to set up a test, and have ran into a problem.

I am using the `Press Key Native` keyword.  http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.5#Press%20Key%20Native  And I'm getting the following error.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Filter                                                           | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'Press Key Native' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My code is:

```
Test Filter
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    9
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    10
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    9
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    10
    Open Browser To Startpage
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    9
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    10
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    9
    Press Key Native    80
    Press Key Native    10
    Open Browser To Google
```

I've been looking all over the Internet and have found nothing.  :-(

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you imported SeleniumLibrary? Are you really using SeleniumLibrary, and not Selenium2Library, which does not have Press Key Native?

Comment: Thank you Harri, you solved my problem!  I'm using Selenium2Library.  I can't give a +1 on a comment but I would otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you mention is part of SeleniumLibrary, which is an old selenium library. The one most people use is Selenium2Library, which doesn't have that keyword. Based on an answer to a comment, it appears you are using the newer Selenium2Library, which is why it is not finding the keyword.